# query text file using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text file on server with all my php scripts which has list of 160,000 words. How can i use javascript or jquery to query against that text file and and check if the word entered by user in a textbox matches any word in the text file?

Answer (score 0):

You should parse that text file and insert the words into a database table, then do AJAX requests with jQuery to a PHP resource that executes a query to the database. Remember to index the word attribute in your database table.

Answer (score 0):

If the file was available to the public server, you could use jQuery...

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var word = $.trim($('#input-word').val());  
   $.get('words.text', function(response) {
       alert(response.test(new RegExp('\b' + word + '\b')) > 0);
   });
});
```

You could use also jQuery and PHP to do that.

#### jQuery

```
$('button').click(function() {
   $.getJSON('word.php', { word: $.trim($('#input-word').val()) }, function(response) {
       alert(response);
   });
});
```

The `alert(response)` will let you know if word was bound on its own in the file.

#### PHP

This filename needs to match above, e.g. `word.php`.

```
<?php

$fileContents = file_get_contents('file.txt');

return json_encode(preg_match('/\b' . preg_quote(trim($_GET['word']), '/') . '\b/', $fileContents));
```

This is untested but it should get you started.

Alternatively if you didn't want to use a regex you could `explode()` on spaces and drop empty array members (or `preg_split('/\s+/')`) and then use `in_array()`, but this will have a bit of overhead.

If performance is an issue, you should perhaps split the text file up and cache its words as array keys to it is `0(1)` (or close enough) to see if the word exists.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use a server side language to communicate with, such as PHP and then use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax.

```
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "my.php?foo=ba", false);
ajax.send(null);
words = ajax.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for since it requires re-structuring of your data, but you may get some useful information out of it and if you're looking for a very quick solution, there are some interesting methods here:

See these posts by John Resig (author of jQuery) about dictionary lookups in JavaScript:

- [Dictionary lookups in JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/blog/dictionary-lookups-in-javascript/)
- [JavaScript trie performance analysis](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/)
- [Revised JavaScript dictionary search](http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/)